# Replacing the attract app in Surface v2

Tags: pixelsense

In Surface v1 it was possible (and fairly easy) to replace the attract app for the device, as per [Microsoft's docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692165%28v=surface.10%29.aspx).  These instructions don't work in Surface v2. [The docs for Surface v2 attract](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg697075.aspx) only talk about changing the background image, which is not enough for me. How can I replace the pre-installed attract app with my own one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the attract app is no longer supported in v2, as far as I know. You could try replacing the exe with something else and seeing what happens, though. :)

Comment: Replacing attract.exe doesn't work either. The new app is visible for a bit and then gets covered over by something else.